# Overwriting provider DNS via cloud-init

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, cloud-init, hetzner, netplan

I want to overrides the DNS given by my cloud provider with my own custom DNS entries. This is a Ubuntu instance so this is configured in netplan. Once my VM boots I can see the following at `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            addresses:
            - 2a01:5f8:c013:170::1/64
            dhcp4: true
            match:
                macaddress: 97:00:01:b7:00:20
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2
                - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1
            routes:
            -   on-link: true
                to: default
                via: fe80::1
            set-name: eth0
```

This is an ipv6 only VM so looks like the provider is explicitly setting all ipv6 info (vs relying on something like DHCP6 or SLAAC). I'm guessing dhcp4 is enabled as some sort of fallback or for local network ipv4 communication since there is no public ipv4 address on this server.

Now I can obviously just change those nameservers and run `netplan apply` followed by `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` and I'm golden. BUT since this netplan file is generated by cloud-init that change will not survive reboots. Therefore I need to customize cloud-init with my provider (Hetzner) by providing a `user-data.yml`.

I only want to override the DNS but keep all other networking info coming from the vendor data so I create a user-data.yml file that looks like this:

```
#cloud-config
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 2a00:1098:2c::1
        - 2a00:1098:2b::1
        - 2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1
```

I spin up a new machine to test it out and no dice. :( It still has the DNS entries coming from my provider and no mention of my custom DNS entries. I must be misunderstanding something about cloud-init. I thought it merged the vendor-data.yml and user-data.yml and gave that to cloud-init but evidently not.

My brute force work-around is to take advantage of the fact that netplan itself can accept a directory of yaml files and merges them together. I drop an extra netplan file with a higher priority via cloud-init and then add an extra reboot since the networking already appears applied by the time the file drops. Example:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
 - path: /etc/netplan/40-nat64-dns.yaml
   content: |
     network:
       version: 2
       ethernets:
         eth0:
           nameservers:
             addresses:
             - 2a00:1098:2c::1
             - 2a00:1098:2b::1
             - 2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1
   permissions: '0644'
runcmd:
 - reboot
```

This works but feels like a hack and I don't like the extra reboot. I could probably avoid the extra reboot by instead just running `netplan apply` and then `systemctl restart systemd-resolved` but the reboot is simpler and more robust then trying to restart the right parts of the networking. Since cloud-init [has a networking config section](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/22.3/topics/network-config-format-v2.html) that is a passthru to netplan it seems like there must be a better way.

---

**Follow-up**

I did find a slightly better solution. Instead of dropping a file for netplan I can drop a file for resolved which seems a bit simpler and then just restart resolved vs netplan and resolved (or the entire server). My new user-data.yml:

```
#cloud-config
write_files:
  - path: /etc/systemd/resolved.conf.d/dns_servers.conf
    content: |
      [Resolve]
      DNS=2a00:1098:2b::1 2a01:4f9:c010:3f02::1 2a01:4f8:c2c:123f::1
      Domains=~.
    permissions: '0644'

runcmd:
  - systemctl restart systemd-resolved
```

Still seems like there should be someway to override the DNS in my user-data.yml directly to netplan since there is a passthru network config.